# How do I amend Web.Config Configuration File?

Tags: 14.04, firefox, mozilla

Whilst attempting to pay for something on the internet, having entered my password etc correctly on the 'Verified by Visa' page I got this message:-

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>


Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Can someone guide me towards a solution please?

Comment: What does a configuration error on some random site have to do with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Web.config is an IIS file, The best thing to do is to ask at Microsoft related forums/mailing list/support sites.